# Locking with S3

Tags: locking, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

What's the recommended way to implement a simple locking mechanism to be used in conjunction with S3?

Example of what I want to do:

- acquire lock by object id
- read object from S3
- modify data
- write object to S3
- release lock

Ideally looking for a cloud based locking mechanism.  I could use memcached locally, but then I have to deal with scaling that.  I don't see an obvious way to implement lightweight locking with any AWS APIs, but it seems like a common problem.

I wonder if you could use SimpleDB to do an atomic acquire lock operation.  Has anyone tried that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I spent some time this morning playing with boto and I think I have a solution that works using SimpleDB.  You need the latest boto release so that conditional puts and consistent reads are supported.

Example code here: http://pastebin.com/3XzhPqfY

Please post comments/suggestions.  I believe this code should be fairly safe -- my test in main() tries it with 10 threads.

One thing I haven't addressed is that S3 reads are not consistent (right?), so in theory a thread may be operating on an old copy of the S3 value.  It looks like there may be a workaround for that as described here:

http://www.shlomoswidler.com/2009/12/read-after-write-consistency-in-amazon.html

Comment: SimpleDB seems to be deprecated now; it's fallen off the AWS console and isn't listed among their 'Services and Solutions' anymore.  Got an implementation that uses DynamoDB? :)

Comment: An update on this answer since it comes up high in search results. S3 reads are now consistent https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/ and the blog post referenced in the answer is gone

Answer (score 2):

i dont think that you can do this using S3 only, using simpleDB's consistency enhancements as james said is a good way that works
you can look for some examples here : [Amazon SimpleDB Consistency Enhancements](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=3572)


another approach that might be fine is using the [versioning feature](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?DataDurability.html#Versioning) of S3
so basically, store an object id/version id pair in simpleDB as the most "valid" version
and assure that all GET requests will retrieve that version
after a successful PUT of a modified object, update the version id in the DB
this way you could also use the ability to retrieve previous versions of an object for restoring if needed.