# Database-less application using S3 for consistency and data-storage

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using a simple submission application which does following for each visitor:

- check the list of directories to find one with largest number in title
- increment that number by one and create new directory
- store the upload into that new directory

I am aware that there is a possible classic race-condition of two simultaneous clients fetching the directory list and determining the same next largest number for them. In order to mitigate the issue, I am using following steps:

- first, get the largest number as before and increment it
- as S3's directories are files, store a random number to the newly created directory
- fetch the directory's contents (the actual file's contents) and compare with what was stored in it
- if the numbers differ, that means that some other thread has "won" the race and thus the process starts again from the step one.

Does this look like enough steps? I was thinking, could network congestion cause a process A to store and read its own number and determine it has won and then a process B would come to the same conclusion. How can I mitigate this? I was thinking about introducing an explicit time-out for the operation - e.g. the directory creation needs to take maximum of n seconds and that would be the time a process would wait before checking for the random number.

Or is there any way to do atomic operation of checking the FS contents and creating the directory, or at least doing create-but-not-replace operation? Or create that would fail instead of replacing existing file?

And btw - I am using PHP and the official SDK.

Comment: This sort of check certainly wouldn't eliminate the possibility of a race condition. The *directory with the largest number in the title* is the bottleneck here and the manipulations involving it should be performed in a critical section. Would that be acceptable?

Also, from your description I have the impression that it will always be the exact same directory that gets the increment. Is that so?

Comment: To clarify - the directory with largest number is not modified, I am after creating a new one - the idea is that every worker process create their own directory with a larger number in the title. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Amazon S3, but there is the following statement [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html):

> Amazon S3 does not currently support object locking. If two puts are
>   simultaneously made to the same key, the put with the latest time
>   stamp wins. If this is an issue, you will need to build an
>   object-locking mechanism into your application.

Along with the rest of the content of the "Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model" section, it suggests that what you would like to do cannot be implemented using requests to Amazon S3 SDK alone, but rather external synchronization is required. One possible recipe using SimpleDB is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431418/locking-with-s3).